# Oracle Internals - varchar and garbage collection

Tags: string, oracle, performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory

My question is based on the following: I have a code block in which I have defined a varchar string, like this:

```
v_string varchar(100);
```

My code block is something like this:

```
...   
v_string := 'x = ' || x || ', y = ' || y;
...
```

That is, `v_string` is a text that I'm using to log `x` and `y` values.

Can anyone explain how Oracle stores such concatenated strings? I mean, does it put these in a heap? If so, will (can) these be garbage collected? Does that affect performance too much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no interim objects created so there will be nothing to garbage collect.

When you declare `v_string`, Oracle allocates 100 bytes of storage (assuming your `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` is the default of `BYTE`) for the string (larger strings will not be pre-allocated like this and what constitutes a "larger string" is version dependent.  In 11.2, the limit appears to be [4000 bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/qrbasic.htm) though it used to be 2000 bytes and I'm not sure when it changed).  Since the 100 byte buffer has been pre-allocated, it's easy enough to concatenate various other strings together in that pre-allocated buffer.  There is no need to allocate any additional space to store interim results so there are no resources to free up.

At some point, `v_string` will go out of scope and the buffer that was allocated for it will be freed, of course.  But that will be at the end of the block where `v_string` is declared.

Comment: What if I need more than 100 bytes? Oracle would probably alocate more space for the string, right? If so, does the old one stay put for gabage collection or is immediately destroyed?
I'm asking this cause I'm creating some strings to log a procedure, and I think the database has slowed down somewhat because I keep creating several rather large strings.
Thanks for the info.

Comment: @kaos12 - If you need more than 100 bytes, you would need to have defined a larger variable.  If you define `v_string` as a `varchar2(100)` in PL/SQL, it will always occupy exactly 100 bytes of memory.  If you are changing the data in a particular PL/SQL variable, there are no old copies kept around to be garbage collected-- everything is done in the pre-allocated buffer.  Of course, string concatenation and searching can be expensive without generating objects that need to be garbage collected.